# Git advanced ignoring

Tags: git, gitignore

My `.gitignore` looks more less like this:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!ImportantDirectory/
!AnotherImportantDirectory

# Actually, ignore these...
ImportantDirectory/NotImportantFile
```

The problem is that `ImportantDirectory/NotImportantFile` is still being tracked. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This is one of the most recurrent types of questions about Git on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had previously included that file, it will continue to be tracked until you remove it from your repository, even if you list it in a .gitignore. Sounds like that is what is happening here. You can do that with:

```
git rm --cached ImportantDirectory/NotImportantFile
```

Note this will remove the file from the .git repository, but will not delete the local file on disk. Note however this will delete `ImportantDirectory/NotImportantFile` for anyone who pulls your git repository, so if this is a file they also need to maintain, but not have included, you may need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore paths which are already tracked.  To fix this, simply move `NotImportantFile` somewhere else, `git rm` it, commit that, then move the file back in place.  Now it will be properly ignored.